# How to increase YSQL timeout in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Running 2.7.1.1 with 3 masters and 5 tservers.

Documentation shows `ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms` overrides the `client_read_write_timeout_ms` gflag. Default for `ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms=-1` but can't find what `-1` means?  Dont override value I am guessing. The `client_read_write_timeout_ms=60000`.

Anyways, tserver are showing timeout at `60s` despite if I change `ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms=300000` and restart tservers.

A simple test:

```
ysqlsh -h x -Ux -d x -c"select count(*) from x.table;"
ERROR: Timed out: [Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Read RPC (request call id 158) to x:9100 timed out after 59.996s, Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Read RPC (request call id 160) to x:9100 timed out after 59.996s, Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Read RPC (request call id 164) to x:9100 timed out after 59.996s, Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Read RPC (request call id 165) to x:9100 timed out after 59.996s, Timed out (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:512): Read RPC (request call id 166) to x:9100 timed out after 59.996s]
```

Tested values on all tservers and masters using curl to verify:

```
curl -s http://x:9000/varz | grep client_read_write_timeout_ms
--client_read_write_timeout_ms=60000
--ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms=300000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [at the code in C++](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/f802b481cb1a90c7df428e82001d28ccbbe4eda1/src/yb/yql/pggate/ybc_pggate.cc#L1065):

```
  const auto default_client_timeout_ms =
      (FLAGS_ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms < 0
           ? std::max(FLAGS_client_read_write_timeout_ms, 600000)
           : FLAGS_ysql_client_read_write_timeout_ms);
```

It means max of `--client_read_write_timeout_ms` and `600000ms`. And, it looks like that code-path is only called when `statement_timeout` session variable is assigned. The common path is `BuildSession`, using `pg_yb_session_timeout_ms` flag. Setting `--pg_yb_session_timeout_ms=300000` in yb-tservers and restarting them should make it work.